# What is a POCO Proxy?

Tags: poco, ado.net-entity-data-model

I came across this term while working on ADO.net entity framework (EF 4.0). It's hard for me to understand this term. I am aware of POCO classes and their use in creating PI model but I am not sure about a POCO proxy.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with dependency injection (DI)? POCO proxies are a form of DI:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/12/22/poco-proxies-part-1.aspx

Comment: I haven't got much idea about DI other than that it allows to dynamically create derived objects with extra set of functionalities. I wanted to use Business Entities across application in of my project involving WCF . I created POCO classes using POCO entity generator but then I got dreaded "Connection close" error. I was using POCO as my data contracts in WCF. I disabled proxy generation , it worked but I still see proxy classes being generated on client side. My idea was to use same business entities on the client as well and not use proxies generated in Service reference

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the technique used to accomplish persistence ignorance where the object is instantiated as a proxy at runtime.  Castle has a proxying framework that you might want to look at to see what sort of thing you can use proxies for.  [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html)